# Telerik Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, testing, drop-down-menu, telerik, telerik-test-studio

Here's the situation:

I am testing a form using Telerik Test Studio.

There are 3 drop downs (State, City, Building) and what you choose on the previous box decides what is in the next box. Before you choose what is in the drop down box number one, two and three are empty (no choices). When you choose a State, it gives you options for cities, then once you choose a city, the building drop down gets populated with options.

The problem is, when I am testing this with the drop downs, it chooses the state correctly, but it, for some reason, doesn't register that there is a state chosen, so the city drop down does not get populated.  I slowed the process down while the test is running to try and see if it was something simple, but I saw myself that it DOES choose a state, so I tried to manually choose the city but there was nothing to populate the drop down options.  But, if I choose the state myself, then the cities populate.

Thank you for your help.

M

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem I am seeing here is you might have missed setting up the ajax call timeout while selecting the 'State' dropdown.

Second option is to click anywhere else on the page after clicking on first dropdown and put some wait after clicking on page so that city values can be loaded after state is selected.